# How to do In-App Purchases ink ivy using Google Play

Tags: android, python, google-play, in-app-purchase, kivy

I have written a kivy android app and was wondering how to implement in-app purchases. I need a good system that won't create too many bugs due to the fact that I don't want to be liable for loads of refunds due to the code not working correctly.  Thanks, Sean

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html read this doc, maybe is gonna help you